# How to zoom font size in SciTE?

Tags: fonts, zoom, scite

I want to zoom the font in SciTE to read easily, and I found [this sample user perference](https://gist.github.com/zdxerr/740426):

```
font.base=font:Consolas,size:11
font.small=font:Consolas,size:8
font.comment=font:Consolas,size:11

font.text=font:Consolas,size:11,fore:#606060
font.text.comment=font:Consolas,size:11
font.embedded.base=font:Consolas,size:11
font.embedded.comment=font:Consolas,size:11
font.monospace=font:Consolas,size:11
font.vbs=font:Consolas,size:
```

However it doesn't seem to change the font after restart. Using <kbd>Ctrl + Numpad+</kbd> doesn't save the setting after restart too. How to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to go to Tool > [Language] setting > Edit style

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To increase the SciTE font size on linux, you need to edit the /etc/scite/SciTEGlobal.properties file. And change the font number, line by line.

if PLAT_GTK

```
    font.base=font:DejaVu Sans,size:13
    font.small=font:DejaVu Sans,size:13
    font.comment=font:DejaVu Serif,size:13
    font.code.comment.box=$(font.comment)
    font.code.comment.line=$(font.comment)
    font.code.comment.doc=$(font.comment)
    font.code.comment.nested=$(font.comment)
    font.text=font:DejaVu Serif,size:13
    font.text.comment=font:Serif,size:13
    font.embedded.base=font:Serif,size:13
    font.embedded.comment=font:Serif,size:13
    font.monospace=font:DejaVu Sans Mono,size:13
    font.monospace.small=font:DejaVu Sans Mono,size:13
    font.vbs=font:DejaVu Sans Mono,size:13
```

Answer (score 0):

i checked this and it works (with my version 4.3.0 on ubuntu 20.04):

go to menu 'options' and there select 'Open User Options File'

a tab in scite opens with this file, which might be empty

put in or edit there to:

> magnification=1
>
> output.magnification=1

and save. done. On next start it is 1 size bigger than standard. Change 1 to whatever you prefer. Incrementing makes it even bigger and decrementing smaller. This are the same steps when pressing
Ctrl + Keypad '+' or Ctrl + Keypad '-' or pressing Ctrl while spinning the mousewheel.

Answer (score 0):

Options:: Open Global Options File

Find and copy the syntax near the bottom.

Open User Options File & paste, then edit.  This will override the global file. For example, I used:

```
 font.base=font:Verdana,size:12
 font.small=font:Verdana,size:10
 font.comment=font:Georgia,size:12
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).